# machine learning octave code gradient descent question

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I'm taking Coursera Machine learning course. so who take this courses will able to help this problem.

this is the octave code to find the delta for gradient descent.

```
     theta = theta - alpha / m * ((X * theta - y)'* X)';//this is the answerkey provided
```

First question)
the way i know to solve the gradient descent theta(0) and theta(1) should  have different approach to get value  as follow

```
     theta(0) = theta(0) - alpha / m * ((X * theta(0) - y)')'; //my answer key
     theta(1) = theta(1) - alpha / m * ((X * theta(1) - y)')'; //my answer key
```

but i'm not sure why the answer key only show

```
            theta = theta - alpha / m * ((X * theta - y)'* X)';
```

this equation.

Second question)  what is the '   ' doing in octave code?

```
            theta = theta - alpha / m * ((X * theta - y)'* X)';
                                '* X)' // what ' ' thing do in here
```

Comment: in octave/matlab, $x =  u+v*w$  can be : $x,u,w$ : 3 vectors, $v$ : a matrix with $v*w$ the multiplication of a matrix with a vector. the main idea of  matlab is that the basic datatypes instead of being integers and floating point numbers, are arrays / matrices  of numbers.

Comment: In Octave, $X'$ corresponds to the transpose of the matrix (or the vector) $X$.

Comment: oh ok so X' means transpose of X. is there someone who knows gradient descent ? I do not understand why they used transpose to find theta here

Comment: I advise you to do basics of programming (preferebly in python) and basics of linear algebra before jumping into machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose here is used for matching the columns of the X with rows of theta.
Ex:
size of 
X=97x2;
y=97x1;
theta=2x1;

first calc is X * theta. The size of the resulting matrix will be 97x1. Then, the sub of two same size matrices. Now, we have to multiply X with the matrix obtained from the previous step. But, the sizes are different
(97x1) * (97x2)

Thus transposing the first matrix makes multiplication possible.
This results in a new matrix of size 1x2 (row vector). But, theta is of size 2x1 (column vector). Hence the final transpose.